# Wordpress drop down to Bootstrap drop down

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap to get drop down menu, here is an example. Now I need to put Wordpress menu items to this code.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I use `wp_nav_menu( array( $args) );` and change $args to my own the arguments don't work.

How can I make it work so any hierarchy level?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try adding this way.

**Register your menus.**

```
function add_wp3menu_support() {

register_nav_menus(
        array(
        'main-menu' => __('Main Navigation'),
        'another-menu' => __('Another Navigation')
        )
     );

}
```

**Add this to your init.**

```
add_action('init', 'add_wp3menu_support');
```

**Add display code:**

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); //displays the menu?>
```

**Finally Display the menu:**

```
<?php
     wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 
    'menu_class' => 'dropdown', 
    'container_id' => 'navwrap', 
    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 
    )
      );
?>
```

Hope this Helps.